# Load created php file data via ajax

Tags: jquery, buddypress, ajax

Ive been trying to do this for a long time here...
First of all, im working with Buddypress latest ver. under WP latest ver.

What i want to do, is i want to understand how to call content within a php file via ajax. I know php is server side, so doing something like this:

```
$(#handle).click( function(){
$(#box).load('help.php' #content);
});
```

will only bring forth html within the document.But I have functions I need within, like let's say for example a user's avatar:

```
<?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar()?>
```

The returned content will stop at the function called. Will I have to create pages for all of the php files that I want to call content from? Or, `require` the file to retrieve the content?

I've looked at some of the `$ajax` Jquery uses around here, but I 'm not sure which one to implement.

I want to load certain content wrapped in specific divs in that php file. Basically, I just need help retrieving content that contains php lol.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you want to hook into the wp_loaded action. Do the stuff you need to do and then exit the process.

You should probably look at http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins